# How to install new opencart theme over an existing theme?

Tags: opencart

How to install a new opencart theme over an existing theme? I want the contents inside the website the same but the appearance should be different.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=opencart+install+theme&oq=opencart+install+theme&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j35i39j69i60.3591j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

1. Each theme comes with install instructions, follow them.
2. In System > Settings > Edit Store, there is a theme drop-down, select your new theme.

[image]